# How can I tell Chrome to use all 6 concurrent connections asap?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, connections

I would like to improve rendering performance of http://www.camping.info/campinplaetze. Running a test on WebPageTest.org I see in the waterfall chart that for images loaded from http://images-camping.info, Chrome initially opens only **three** connections, and only at the 2 second marks opens another three. That's why the first 6 images are loaded consecutively, all on the third open connection as seen in the connection view:

[image: Resource view]
[image: Connection view]

I would like Chrome to open the **six** concurrent connections to images-camping.info around the 1 second mark so that it could download more images in parallel which I assume would make rendering the page faster.

Does anyone know of a way to do that?

Comment: Running HTTP/2 will probably give you an even better pipeline for serving multiple resources.

Comment: It's probably time to turn this on in our NGINX server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer - every browser has a specific [limit to open parallel connections.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160209092324/http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network)** In the case of Chrome this limit is **10**.

If I was there, I would do only two things:

1. Optimize images - If you're using png files, then I suggest to use [tinypng.com](http://tinypng.com), because it compresses images well, compared to Google PageSpeed module.
2. Serve Images from CDN - Use Amazon Cloudfront CDN to serve images, because image URL begin with Amazon Cloudfront URL, so you don't need to use second domain, [here is an example](https://d1avok0lzls2w.cloudfront.net/uploads/blog/56c65618708df2.22042456.jpg) of how they serve images with their domain name. CDN helps in [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145277/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-a-content-delivery-network-c).

Comment: From you link I can see that Chrome uses only up to **10** parallel connections - this explains my observations perfectly. Thanks also for the other tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can have several subdomains (CNAMEs) and load some resources via them, eg:

- css.domain.com
- js.domain.com

or, better, assets1, assets2 etc. They all point to the same server, but in your page sources you use different subdomains to trick the browser around

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a fullfit answer because I am not sure if you can tell Chrome how to load your page, but least you can do is to optimize your website.

1. Starting with `Expire Headers`, make sure they are working
   correctly, not just for images but for basically everything.
2. Optimize the pictures in your website, I believe you have done that
       but if you haven't yet, then use an online convertor like
       tinypng.com or other to compress your images.
3. Use `.gzip`
           compression for src files and minify them.

There are sure more things to dig into performance optimization but I think you should consider to start with these three basic things and if they help you I can give you further advices.